# How to capture "Select all" event of context menu in plain javascript

Tags: contextmenu

I have an HTML canvas application. I want to support right click "select all" command. I added an textarea on top of canvas to capture text editing events like cut, copy, paste and select all. I can capture all other commands using "oncut", "oncopy", etc., except "Select all" which I could not find the corresponding event for it. What I plan to do is that when user right click on textarea then click "Select all", my event handler is called and do a "Select all" in my canvas.

Answer (score 3):

I have found the answer: "Select all" context menu command will fire onselectstart event.

Comment: For further reference, see [onselectstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onselectstart). It would be great to show an example of your working code here.